# How to formulate this multi-thread programming scenario?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to use multi-thread to traverse a tree structure. The issue here is, the structure of the tree is not known without an HTTP call (i.e., an HTTP call will give you the children of the node). Therefore, I'm trying to use multi-thread to increase the throughput of HTTP requests we can make.

I don't know how we should solve this problem nicely so I'll try to describe my thoughts here first.

Initially I think it would be similar to what we normally write in BFS, assuming we have a concurrency level of 10.

```
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10);

Task HTTPGet(Node node) {
  blah blah
  Q.push(childNodes);
}

while (!Q.isEmpty()) {
    Node node = Q.head();
    Q.pop();
    taskList.Add(Task.Start(() => HTTPGet(node));
}
```

The issue here is: after processing the first node, Q becomes empty and the whole loop will be terminated. So then I feel we need to check the remaining count of the semaphore as well. So if the remaining count of semaphore is not 10, it means some process is still working and we should wait for its process instead.

```
while (!Q.isEmpty() || semaphore.Count != 10) {
    Node node = Q.head();
    Q.pop();
    taskList.Add(Task.Start(() => HTTPGet(node));
}
```

But apparently after the first node gets popped, Q is still empty and we need to do some "wait" inside the while loop to make sure we can get the node.

```
while (!Q.isEmpty() || semaphore.Count != 10) {
    if (Q.isEmpty()) {
       Wait till Q becomes non empty
       or semaphore.Count == 10 again
    }
    Node node = Q.head();
    Q.pop();
    taskList.Add(Task.Start(() => HTTPGet(node));
}
```

But then this becomes so ugly and I'm pretty sure there should be a better way to solve this problem. I'm trying to formulate it in producer-consumer paradigm but failed (since this time the consumer will also start more producers).

Is there a better way to formulate this problem?

Comment: Is the tree structure guaranteed to be non-cyclic, or can there be child nodes that point back to a parent (or higher) node, as is generally true in a normal website?

Comment: @MattJordan: The structure is guaranteed to be acyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to explain via code, but be mindful that this is not something I have tried or tested. This is for you to get started on the correct path

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        new Program();
    }

    Program() {
        Node root = new Node("root");
        root.Children = new Node[2];
        root.Children[0] = new Node("child0");
        root.Children[1] = new Node("child1");

        MultiThreadedBFS(root);

    }


    BlockingCollection<Node> Queue = new BlockingCollection<Node>(10); // Limit it to the number of threads

    Node[] HTTPGet(Node parentNode) {
        return parentNode.Children; //your logic to fetch nodes go here
    }

    volatile int ThreadCount;

    void MultiThreadedBFS(Node root) {
        Queue.Add(root);

        // we fetch each node's children on a separate thread. 
        // This means that when all nodes are fetched, there are 
        // no more threads left. That will be our exit criteria
        ThreadCount = 0;

        do {
            var node = FetchNextNode();
            if (node == null)
                break;

            ProcessNode(node);
        } while (true);

    }

    Node FetchNextNode() {
        Node node;
        while (!Queue.TryTake(out node, 100)) {
            if (ThreadCount == 0 && Queue.Count == 0)
                return null; // All nodes have been fetched now
        }

        return node;
    }

    void ProcessNode(Node node) {
        // you can use a threadpool or task here
        new Thread(() => {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "ChildThread";

            ++ThreadCount;
            Debug.WriteLine("Retrieving children for Node: " + node);
            var children = HTTPGet(node);
            foreach (var child in children) {
                Debug.WriteLine("Adding node for further processing: " + node);
                while (!Queue.TryAdd(child, -1))
                    ;
            }

            --ThreadCount;

        }).Start();
    }

    // this is the actual node class that represents the Node on the tree
    [DebuggerDisplay("Name = {Name}")]
    class Node {
        public string Name;
        public Node[] Children = new Node[0];

        public Node(string name) {
            Name = name;
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return Name;
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

I have updated the program now to fix the exit criteria and some other bugs

Also, even though I am using threads here, I think this is a perfect case for using async/await. I will let someone else answer using async/await

Comment: Thanks! I have a quick question though - suppose we've reached the leaf level and we've already pushed the leaf level to the queue. Now the thread processing the leaf node has already started so the loop runs again to "while (!Queue.TryTake(out node, -1))" statement. Since it's at the leaf level, no children will be pushed to the queue. So the loop will get stuck at "TryTake" statement no matter how long it waits?

Comment: @derekhh I just updated the code to fix the issue you pointed out, and some other exit criteria bugs

Answer (score 0):

Before taking from the queue make each thread increment a counter of threads pulling from the queue right now. If that counter reaches the number of threads exactly this means that all threads are trying to dequeue and there can't possibly be any operation in progress. In that case signal all threads to exit.